# Aplicação JSF em cluster

Tags: java, jsf, session, tomcat, replicação

O que minha aplicação (JSF + Primefaces) precisa ter para trabalhar em cluster?

Estou fazendo um teste em um ambiente com 3 Tomcat em cluster (com replicação de sessão) e minha aplicação teste não funciona.

A princípio, só incluí a tag `<distributable/>` no web.xml.

O app é bem simples, só um `@ManagedBean` `@SessionScope` e um xhtml com um botão para incrementar uma variável.

Quando a requisição pula de um servidor para o outro a sessão se perde.

*Obs:*

*O ambiente parece que está configurado certo e funcionando, pois há uma página JSP que funciona.*

*Fonte: [Ramki Java Blog - Tomcat Clustering Series](http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/12/tomcat-clustering-series-part-4-session.html)*

Answer (score 2):

Se você está usando tomcat de sessão você deve fazer algo para compartilhar a sessão entre o tomcat.

Uma abordagem é chamada de StickSession onde você define apenas uma máquina para determinado cliente e direciona todas as chamadas dele para lá. O problema dessa abordagem é que se a máquina cair, a sessão do cara se perde.

Outra abordagem seria salvar a sessão em banco, desse modo tudo está persistido lá e poderia ser compartilhado.

E outra soluçao é essa aqui da própria tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html